# How does the intermediate value property differ from the value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

IVP: A function $f$ has the intermediate value property on an interval $[a,b]$ if for all $x < y$ in $[a,b]$ and all $L$ between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$, it is always possible to find a point $c \in (x,y)$ where $f(c) = L$

And

IVT: If $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and if $L$ is a real number satisfying $f(a) < L < f(b)$ or $f(a) > L > f(b)$ then there exists a point $c \in (a,b)$ where $f(c) = L$

Both definitions seem very similar to me, what purpose do they serve individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to state the IVT is:  If $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, then $f$ has the IVP.

So the IVP is a property, the IVT is the statement that continuous functions have the IVP!

Comment: And there exist functions with the IVP that are not continous

Comment: Derivatives, for example.

Comment: Excellent, thank-you